# Entity Data Source in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток!
Во время работы с EF и WinForms возникла трудность при добавлении элемента **Entity Data Source**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключение к ADO.NET EDM я организовал с помощью Code First. И стандартные операции типа:

```
db.Tools.Load();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Tools.Local.ToBindingList();
```

выполняются.

Comment: *возникла трудность при добавлении элемента Entity Data Source* - так, а дальше что? В чем трудность? В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Может быть имеется смысл почитать немного мануалы, если у Вас *на скриншоте присутствует описание причины*? Не думаю, что в тултипе просто так написано про `ADO.NET`.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, спасибо за совет! Но я так и сделал, перед тем как задавать вопрос. Я установил [DynamicData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.EFProvider/) и [EntityDataSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource/), но всё равно не получается добавить компонент. Также не получается добавить ссылку на данную библиотеку.

Comment: При возможности я попытаюсь воспроизвести Вашу проблему, если вопрос будет актуален. Но, чтобы я не задавал дополнительных вопросов, внесите уточняющую правку в вопрос. Что Вы делаете по шагам и что не вышло. Тогда будет проще дать ответ. Как я понял, создать WinForms проект и добавить EntityDataSource в него не получается.

Comment: Также, имеется вопрос, а есть ли у Вас 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' и насколько правильно Вы все делаете. К чему это я? Да вот к чему: [Entity Framework in WinForms](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/221931/entity-framework-in-winforms) очень подробно разжевано. Разобраться можно, хоть и на английском. Просто исходя из Вашего вопроса совсем не ясно что у Вас именно есть и как Вы это делаете.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, да, я делал всё по этому [руководству](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/221931/entity-framework-in-winforms?msg=4528028#xx4528028xx), так же есть перевод на [habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275607/). По шагам: 1) Добавил в проект ADO.NET EDM (пробовал через Code first и Database). 2) Создал экземпляр контекста, загрузил его, и передал его в Datasource DataGrid-a. 3) Затем в руководстве написано(**Создание Grid View (With AutoLookup)**): _"Чтобы устранить эти недостатки, добавьте на форму компонент EntityDataSource."_

Comment: Но у меня не получается добавить данный компонент , т.к в Toolbox-e его просто нет, а когда выбираю "все", то не получается его добавить на форму.